# Duplicate Xcode target from AppleScript

Tags: xcode, applescript

I need an AppleScript that opens an Xcode project and duplicates its last target.

I've found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388359) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694750) but none of them seem to work (at least with Xcode 9.1).

I've tried this:

```
do shell script "open <myproject>"
tell application "Xcode"
    tell active workspace document
        tell first project
            duplicate last target
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But it fails with:

> execution error: Error in Xcode: Can not set last target of project 1 of active workspace document to last target of project 1 of active workspace document. (-1006)

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has obviously removed `duplicate` from the commands in the Standard Suite. That means the `target` class does not respond to `duplicate`.

Unfortunately the UI elements in the project navigator have no `actions` so you can't select the target and press <kbd>⌘D</kbd> with GUI scripting either.

So the only way to duplicate a target programmatically is a third party solution like Keyboard Maestro which is able to perform a mouse click on a specific location to simulate *select the project* -> *select the target* -> *Press  <kbd>⌘D</kbd>*